# muted HTML5 Video on iOS not unmutable

Tags: ios, html5-video

I use HTML5 Videos with VideoJS on a website and when the video comes into the viewport, it automatically starts playing. But I mute the video before it starts playing since we don't want to annoy people.

```
video.prop('muted', true);
video[0].play();
```

The problem I encountered is, that the video can't be unmuted on iOS 10.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: <video controls muted></video> try muting it in the tag itself

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't make any difference. There is still no button to unmute on iOS. On Android it's there.

Comment: DO one thing, is it possible to provide an external button(out side video tag), on click you can mute and unmute the video tag.

Comment: Or in the video tag set up progress event or canPlay event, on which you can unmute video tag from java script.

Comment: The external button won't work, since the video shows in fullscreen in iPhones. The canPlay event wont work either because I don't want the video to be unmuted when it starts because it's in the viewport. I just want the user to manually unmute it.

Answer (score 0):

The Property of mute does not work in ios, and you are saying its muted all the way, please check if the device is on silent, I have faced the same problem but when i checked my device was on silent mode an

Comment: Do you have a source stating that mute doesn't work in ios?