# Mute the sound on exit fullscreen mode in the HTML video player

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video, fullscreen

I need to fix problems with the full-screen mode in the HTML video player.
The video is playing in the background, but there is a play button that starts the video in full-screen mode and turns on the sound. When the user exits full-screen mode - the sound should be muted.
The problem appears on iOS.

```
  <div class="content">
    <video
      autoplay
      muted
      loop
      id="videoAnimation"
     
    >
      <source
        src="https://videosource.mp4"
        type="video/mp4"
      />
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="heading">
    <button
      class="fullScreen"
      onclick="goFullscreen('player'); return false"
    ></button>
  </div>

  <script>
        document.getElementById("videoAnimation").play();
    var video = document.getElementById("videoAnimation");
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    function goFullscreen(id) {
      var element = document.getElementById("videoAnimation");
      if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
      }
      if (video.muted) {
        video.muted = false;
      } else {
        video.muted = false;
      }
    }

    video.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", function () {
      if (video.muted) {
        video.muted = false;
      } else {
        video.muted = true;
      }
    });
    video.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function () {
      if (video.muted) {
        video.muted = false;
      } else {
        video.muted = true;
      }
    });
  </script>
```

I have tried to add addEventListener for fullscreen, but it ruined button functionality on iOS. But works fine on other OS and browsers. Does anyone know the correct JS corrections to make this work on all systems?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634376/muted-html5-video-on-ios-not-unmutable

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
var video = document.getElementById("videoAnimation");
      var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
      
      function goFullscreen(id) {
        var element = document.getElementById("videoAnimation");
        if (element.requestFullscreen) {
          element.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
          element.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
          element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        // } else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
          element.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
    
        video.muted = false;
      }
    
      function exitFullscreen() {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
          document.exitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
          document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
          document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
          document.msExitFullscreen();
        }
    
        video.muted = true;
      }
    
      document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function () {
        if (document.fullscreenElement) {
          video.muted = false;
        } else {
          video.muted = true;
        }
      });
    
      document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function () {
        if (document.webkitIsFullScreen) {
          video.muted = false;
        } else {
          video.muted = true;
        }
      });
      </script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).